# Schedule reels Facebook with API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How to schedule reels with API Facebook

```
let postData = {
            upload_phase: 'finish',
            video_state: 'SCHEDULED',
            scheduled_publish_time: 1698916264,//await getTime(),
            // is_scheduled:true,
            description: caption,
            access_token: token,
            video_id: session.data.video_id
        };

        let response = await axios.post(`https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/${pageId}/video_reels`, postData);
        console.log(response.data);
```

[image]

I use this code:

```
let postData = {
            upload_phase: 'finish',
            video_state: 'SCHEDULED',
            scheduled_publish_time: 1698916264,//await getTime(),
            // is_scheduled:true,
            description: caption,
            access_token: token,
            video_id: session.data.video_id
        };

        let response = await axios.post(`https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/${pageId}/video_reels`, postData);
        console.log(response.data);
```